# CSS Not using correct font-size

Tags: html, css, font-size

When I open the webpage in Chrome the first card-text div uses the font-size of 22px but the second card-text div indicates a font-size of 22px but uses a font-size of 13.75px. Both divs indicate that the same class is being used: @media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (orientation: portrait).

I´m unable to find any solution to what might cause this problem. I hope someone can give me some direction to where I could look for this problem...

```css
.card-text {
  color: var(--standard-text-color);
  font-family: standard-font;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .card-text {
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 350px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .card-text {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-title">Welcome</div>
  <div class="card-text">This is some text</div>
  <div class="card-hidden">
    <div class="card-text">This is some other text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem could be a number of things. Please provide more information.

Comment: The 13.75px is a computed style, when I click the arrow it takes me to the class with a minimal width of 350px.

Comment: Do you have a link or more complete code please?

Comment: Please provide an actual example of the issue using Snippets (the <> button in the question editor), [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may or may not work, but try put this in your HTML head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This did work out, I was planning to add a viewport after completing the stylesheets. Until yesterday the website did display correctly and I was using media queries before. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too much for a comment, so i write it as an answer: Reasons could be CSS rules containing a different font size with

- a combined selector `.card-hidden .card-text` (only affecting the second `.card-text`)
- a combined selector  `.card > .card-text` (only affecting the first `.card-text`)
- a selector `card-text:nth-child(2);` (only affecting the first `.card-text`) or `card-text:first-child;` (only affecting the second `.card-text`)

and probably also some more, but not knowing the whole code it can't be said which.

All these would override the regular `.card-text` rule due to their specifity.

Last but not least it can also be overridden by a regular CSS rule for `.card-text`  which follows *after* all the other rules (also *after* media queries), thereby overwriting them.